# Is there any sample code to check PagedResultDto in asp.net boilerplate

Tags: paging, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to override getall method but i am getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'items' of
>   'PagedResultDto.PagedResultDto(int,
>   IReadOnlyList)' fs.Application  C:\Projects\fs\3.2\aspnet-core\src\fs.Application\Location\StateService.cs  35  Active

This is my code

```
public override Task<PagedResultDto<StateDto>> GetAll(PagedResultRequestDto input)
        {
            var query = _repository.GetAll();
            var statelist = query.Skip(input.SkipCount).Take(input.MaxResultCount).ToList();
            return new PagedResultDto<StateDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<StateDto>>(statelist));
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the [`totalCount`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/cbc100d2e4dad8fb1927fa71a8b3182f77d30481/src/Abp/Application/Services/Dto/PagedResultDto.cs#L31) parameter:

```
new PagedResultDto<StateDto>(query.Count(), ObjectMapper.Map<List<StateDto>>(statelist));
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Abp.Application.Services.Dto.PagedResultDto' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>‌​' fs.Application   C:\‌​Projects\fs\3.2\aspn‌​et-core\src\fs.Appli‌​cation\Location\Stat‌​eService.cs  36

Wrap result in a `Task` like this:

```
var result = new PagedResultDto<StateDto>(...);
return Task.FromResult(result);
```